Install cyvfleat (Python)
I am trying to use the file https://www.di.ens.fr/willow/teaching/recvis_orig/assignment1/install_cyvlfeat.py to install cyvlfeat (because I need functions available in this version of cyvfleat but not in the newest ones).
And I cannot make it work.
I am on AlmaLinux 9.4 (Seafoam Ocelot).
I tried using a conda environment with python 3.9, I get something like:
File "/Data/user/miniconda3/envs/deep4/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 571, in run
   raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'VLFEAT_DIR="$(dirname `pwd`)/vlfeat-0.9.20/" python setup.py build' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/user/install_cyvlfeat.py", line 86, in <module>
    print(str(e, 'utf-8'))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, CalledProcessError found


I cannot make it work on Google Colab either.
I used python 3.5, it works better:
installing cython... done!
building cyvlfeat... done!
installing cyvlfeat... done! NOTE: to uninstall run: cat cyvlfeat_files.txt | xargs rm -rf
copying vlfeat dynamic libary to a reachable location... WARNING: The dynamic lib has been copied to your current directory.
To make it accessible please run:
       export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
and restart the notebook server
done!
Installation of cyvlfeat is finished

If I use
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH 

and run a python script, it works.
But how do I make it work in a notebook ?
Specifically, I am using VS Code.
Thank you for your help.
